# YUI ResultHighlighters - Issues

Tags: autocomplete, yui

I am trying to integrate this Yahoo finance look up into a financial website.

http://albertosantini.github.io/examples/getquote/ac_getquote_yahoo.html

Everything works great. But, the results are not highlighting. I added auto highlight module , still didn't work. Here is modified code
 YUI({
    filter: 'raw'
}).use('datasource-get', 'datasource-jsonschema', 'autocomplete','autocomplete-highlighters', function (Y) {

acNode.plug(Y.Plugin.AutoComplete, {
        maxResults: 10,
        resultTextLocator: 'symbol',
        resultHighlighter: 'phraseMatch',
        resultFormatter: function (query, results) {
            return Y.Array.map(results, function (result) {
                var asset = result.raw;

...........

Any hep here is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

View this post here. We made it work.

http://yuilibrary.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=92&t=6709

Added highlighter while formatting the results.